# Unable to auto-generate resolvers after updating schema in AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

```
input AMPLIFY {
  globalAuthRule: AuthRule = {allow: public}
}

input CreateVviraldataInput {
  id: String!
  project: String
  operator: String
  product: String
  result_1: String
  result_2: String
}

type vviraldata {
  id: String!
  project: String
  operator: String
  product: String
  result_1: String
  result_2: String
}

input UpdateVviraldataInput {
  id: String!
  project: String
  operator: String
  product: String
  result_1: String
  result_2: String
}

type Mutation {
  deleteVviraldata(id: Int!): vviraldata
  createVviraldata(createVviraldataInput: CreateVviraldataInput!): vviraldata
  updateVviraldata(updateVviraldataInput: UpdateVviraldataInput!): vviraldata
  deleteCustomers(id: Int!): Customers
  createCustomers(createCustomersInput: CreateCustomersInput!): Customers
  updateCustomers(updateCustomersInput: UpdateCustomersInput!): Customers
  deleteChromatography(id: Int!): Chromatography
  createChromatography(createChromatographyInput: CreateChromatographyInput!): Chromatography
  updateChromatography(updateChromatographyInput: UpdateChromatographyInput!): Chromatography
  deleteSampleData(id: Int!): SampleData
  createSampleData(createSampleDataInput: CreateSampleDataInput!): SampleData
  updateSampleData(updateSampleDataInput: UpdateSampleDataInput!): SampleData
}

type Query {
  getVviraldata(id: Int!): vviraldata
  listVviraldatas: [vviraldata]
  getCustomers(id: Int!): Customers
  listCustomerss: [Customers]
  getChromatography(id: Int!): Chromatography
  listChromatographys: [Chromatography]
  getSampleData(id: Int!): SampleData
  listSampleDatas: [SampleData]
}

type Subscription {
  onCreateVviraldata: vviraldata @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createVviraldata"])
  onCreateCustomers: Customers @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createCustomers"])
  onCreateChromatography: Chromatography @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createChromatography"])
  onCreateSampleData: SampleData @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createSampleData"])
}

schema {
  query: Query
  mutation: Mutation
  subscription: Subscription
}

input CreateCustomersInput {
  id: Int!
  name: String!
  phone: String!
  email: String!
}

type Customers {
  id: Int!
  name: String!
  phone: String!
  email: String!
}

input UpdateCustomersInput {
  id: Int!
  name: String
  phone: String
  email: String
}

input CreateChromatographyInput {
  id: String!
  project: String!
  operator: String!
  date: String!
  product: String!
  feedstocktype: String!
  cellline: String!
  producttiter: String!
  hcptiter: String!
  impuritiestiter: String!
  samplevolume: String!
  samplesource: String!
  purificationmode: String!
  purificationtype: String!
  ligandid: String!
  studyreplicatenumber: String!
  columnheight: String!
  columndiameter: String!
  columnvolume: String!
  result_1: String
  result_2: String
}

type Chromatography {
  id: String!
  project: String!
  operator: String!
  date: String!
  product: String!
  feedstocktype: String!
  cellline: String!
  producttiter: String!
  hcptiter: String!
  impuritiestiter: String!
  samplevolume: String!
  samplesource: String!
  purificationmode: String!
  purificationtype: String!
  ligandid: String!
  studyreplicatenumber: String!
  columnheight: String!
  columndiameter: String!
  columnvolume: String!
  result_1: String
  result_2: String
}

input UpdateChromatographyInput {
  id: String!
  project: String
  operator: String
  date: String
  product: String
  result_1: String
  result_2: String
  feedstocktype: String
  cellline: String
  producttiter: String
  hcptiter: String
  impuritiestiter: String
  samplevolume: String
  samplesource: String
  purificationmode: String
  purificationtype: String
  ligandid: String
  studyreplicatenumber: String
  columnheight: String
  columndiameter: String
  columnvolume: String
}

input CreateSampleDataInput {
  id: Int!
  sourcename: String!
  operator: String!
  volume: String!
  product: String!
  feedstock: String
}

type SampleData {
  id: Int!
  sourcename: String!
  operator: String!
  volume: String!
  product: String!
  feedstock: String
}

type Elisa {
  projectName: String!
  operatorName: String!
  date: String!
  elisaBrand: String!
  targetOrAavSerotype: String!
  kitCatalogNo: String!
  kitLotNo: String!
}

input UpdateSampleDataInput {
  id: Int!
  sourcename: String
  operator: String
  volume: String
  product: String
  feedstock: String
}`
```

I have added a new type Elisa and ran the 'amplify update api' command. amplify codegen doesnt seem to create the mutations for me. I had managed to previously make it work for other inputs SampleData using the command amplify add graphql datasource, but that does not seem to work. Would appreciate the help.

I want the auto generated code which usually comes after I run the command.